# Excel: Calculate average daily usages of gas based on date and time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

awkward question to word. I'm using Excel and would like to calculate the average usage of gas in my house. I have got a list of times and dates which I write down when I get chance or remember, is there a good way to do this?

I would like to use cell formulas by the way.

An example of the data I have to work with:

```
  Date/Time         Gas   Electric
25/01/15 01:48    £10.62    £3.38
                           +£5.00
26/01/15 01:48    £8.56     £6.92
26/01/15 02:00    £8.18     £6.45
27/01/15 13.19    £7.44     £6.03
27/01/15 18.00    £7.06     £5.57
27/01/15 19:50    £7.06     £5.41
27/01/15 21:14    £6.97     £5.26
```

**Edit:** 
Using TriHard8's answer, this is what is produced
[image]

Does this mean that 0.70 pence is used each hour based on the two times?

**Edit 2:**
Still getting negative numbers :S 
[image]

Comment: Do you want gas/hour?  gas/minute?  You can convert dates and times to integers to do math with them.

Comment: gas/day would be ideal. So maybe detect when it's a new day work out how much has been used, and maybe fill in the gaps when I didn't write down how much used throughout the rest of the day, if that makes sense?

Comment: I made a few mistakes, but it should be good now.  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: The average is just (First reading - Last reading) / (Last time - First time) so the times and readings in between are irrelevant.

Comment: The units should be £ / day. As you used about £2 of credit in a day, the answer should be around 2 (or -2, since the credit is going down). That's what I got when I tried it, but I can't work out how it came to -.70 in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gas used between 2 dates/times divided by ((Date2 + Time2) - (Date1 + Time1)).  (10.62 - 8.56) / ( (26/01/15 + 01:48) - (25/01/15 + 01:48) )

Put this formula into H6: =( F5 - F6 ) / ( (D6+E6) - (D5+E5) )
This will be use per day.  It doesn't matter if you compare 2 measurements from the same day, or over 20 days, it will be the average per day.

You need to make sure that you format the resulting cell to be a number, with whatever precision you'd like.

Comment: Why did you put SUM?  Should be =(10.62 - 8.56) / ( (25/01/15 + 01:48) - (26/04/15+01:48) )

Comment: @MartynBall I redid my answer.  I was in a hurry and kept switching signs.  You shouldn't end up with a negative number.

Comment: Updated my post again

Comment: @MartynBall I noticed that earlier.  Something is wrong with your data.  On Jan 27 at 4:33AM you have 7.44 units of gas, but on Jan 27 at 1:26AM (before 4:33AM) you have 7.06 units.  So unless someone filled gas in that 3 hours, your data is incorrect.  Is 1:26AM supposed to be 13:26?  Also, you entered the formula incorrectly b/c H6 should be 2.23.  Which means you used 2.23 units per day based on the 2 dates.